# Stopwatch with multiple displays

Tags: javascript, mysql

Hi there i am currently using a javascript stopwatch (found online) i have made a few changes but got to this point and not sure how to proceed, i want to have one stopwatch running but for it display multiple times (depending on how many users are in the mysql table) i have managed to get it to run more than one at a time but it always crashes my browser so im assuming i was doing it the incorrect way?
my javascript is

```js
 var flagclock = 0;
 var flagstop = 0;
 var stoptime = 0;
 var splitcounter = 0;
 var currenttime;
 var splitdate = '';
 var output;
 var output1;
 var clock;
 
 function startstop()
  {
  
  var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
  
 
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if(flagclock==0)
   {
   startstop.value = 'Stop';
   flagclock = 1;
   counter(starttime);
   }
  else
   {
   startstop.value = 'Start';
   flagclock = 0;
   flagstop = 1;
   splitdate = '';
   }
  }
  

 function counter(starttime)
  {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  
  
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if(flagstop == 1)
   {
   timediff = timediff + stoptime
   }
  if(flagclock == 1)
   {
   clock.value = formattime(timediff,'');
   refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');',10);
   }
  else
   {
   window.clearTimeout(refresh);
   stoptime = timediff;
   }
  
  }

 function formattime(rawtime,roundtype)
  {
  if(roundtype == 'round')
   {
   var ddds = Math.round(rawtime/1) + '';
   }
  else
   {
   var ddds = Math.floor(rawtime/1) + '';
   }
  if(roundtype == 'round')
   {
   var dds = Math.round(rawtime/10) + '';
   }
  else
   {
   var dds = Math.floor(rawtime/10) + '';
   }
  if(roundtype == 'round')
   {
   var ds = Math.round(rawtime/100) + '';
   }
  else
   {
   var ds = Math.floor(rawtime/100) + '';
   }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime/1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime/60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  dds = dds.charAt(dds.length - 1);
  ddds = ddds.charAt(ddds.length - 1);
  if(min >= 60)
   {
   startstop();
   }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if(sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '')
   {
   sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
   }
  else
   {
   sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
   }
  min = min + '';
  if(min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '')
   {
   min = min.charAt(min.length - 2)+min.charAt(min.length - 1);
   }
  else
   {
   min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
   }
  return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds + dds + ddds;
  }

 function resetclock()
  {
  flagstop = 0;
  stoptime = 0;
  splitdate = '';
  window.clearTimeout(refresh);
  output.value = '';
  output1.value = '';
  splitcounter = 0;
  if(flagclock == 1)
   {
   var resetdate = new Date();
   var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
   counter(resettime);
   }
  else
   {
   clock.value = "00:00:000";  
   }
  }
  

 function splittime()
  {
  if(flagclock == 1)
   {
   if(splitdate != '')
    {
    var splitold = splitdate.split(':');

    var splitnow = clock.value.split(':');
    
    var numbers = new Array();
    var i = 0
    for(i;i<splitold.length;i++)
     {
     numbers[i] = new Array();
     numbers[i][0] = splitold[i]*1;
     numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i]*1;
     }
    if(numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0])
     {
     numbers[1][1] += 60;
     numbers[0][1] -= 1;
     }
    if(numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0])
     {
     numbers[2][1] += 10;
     numbers[1][1] -= 1;
     }
    var mzeros = (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) < 10?'0':'';
    var szeros = (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) < 10?'0':'';
    output1.value += '\t+' + mzeros + (numbers[0][1] - numbers[0][0]) + ':' + szeros + (numbers[1][1] - numbers[1][0]) + ':' + (numbers[2][1] - numbers[2][0]) + '\n';
    }
   
   splitdate = clock.value;
   output.value = (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.value + '\n';
   
   }
  }
```

```html
 <input id="clock" name="clock" type="text" value="00:00.000" style="text-align: center;" readonly>
 <input id="clock" name="clock" type="text" value="00:00.000" style="text-align: center;" readonly><br>
 
 <input id="startstopbutton" type="button" value="Start" onClick="startstop();"><br>
 <input id="splitbutton" type="button" value="Split time" onClick="splittime();"><br>
 <input id="resetbutton" type="button" value="Reset" onClick="resetclock();"><br>
 
 <input id="output" type="text" style="text-align: center;" readonly><input id="output" type="text" style="text-align: center;" readonly><br>
 
 <textarea id="output1" style="height: 20%;"></textarea><textarea id="output1" style="height: 20%;"></textarea>
```

So when the start button is pressed i want it to display both stopwatches not just the one, same for split time. i have to use the id (or something similar) as when the script is put into my coding it will be fed from my database so the id will be the same for multiple users

Comment: I ran an HTML page consisting of the code you give above with Firefox. It does not crash but only one clock runs. Is this because you have given two clock displays with the same id, which is `id="clock"` ?

Comment: i know it doesnt work as they both have the same id (one does work) thats what im trying to get around i want both to work well more than two in some cases but unsure on how to go about it, as when it is placed on my site it will be fed from a mysql so <input id="clock" name="clock" type="text" value="00:00.000" style="text-align: center;" readonly><br> will come up for every user in the table?

Comment: You can create HTML content such as e.g. `<div id="clock1"><input id="clockUser99" ...</div>` based on your database. Try exploring `innerHTML`. You can build a string `content` defining an element's content, then use a JavaScript statement such as `document.getElementById('clock1').innerHTML = content;` to replace the div container's content

Comment: I realise that doesn't actually solve the problem, but the ideas might help: alter the HTML code dynamically. Perhaps you can then also pass the `id` to your clock functions.

Comment: i understand what you mean apart from building a string `content` i somehow need to get the function to run `clock =` witch im assuming is a function? sorry rather new to javascript. i tried your suggestion and i think it could work if i can get the clock function to run? :S

Comment: Here is a simple function that sets the content of a container. `function setcontent(id, usernum) { document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'Hello User ' + usernum; }` I can't rewrite or adapt the code you borrowed, but perhaps you could start afresh and write your own code based on it, bearing in mind that you can dynamically create content.

Comment: Well i just tried 'getElementsByClassName' and still had no luck as i have read you cant use id more than once but class you can? i would love to write my own code but i have a funny feeling i wouldnt get very far, im thinking of trying to get the stopwatch code with start stop and reset to work with multiple displays then going from there? if you feel you can modify the code to make it work and dont mind doing so i would really appreciate it? thanks for the advice so far